# Loop through database and update a field with a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to round a decimal from a table and update another field in the same table with the new rounded value, but I just cant seem to hack it.

The rounding script works perfectly, but I am stuck trying to run the rounding script and update the database accordingly.

The table consist of over 10,000 entries, thus I request only data of a specific given date, which narrows down to about 1,200 entries at a time...

Here is my foreach loop (which works well on its own), but this is not working:

```
<?php
include("XXXX");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
$query = "SELECT `sub_hrs`, `id` FROM `attend` WHERE `date` = '$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);  
    $n = array($sub_hrs);
    foreach($n as $i) {
        $new[] = (fmod($i, 1) > 0.5 
                ? sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i + 0.5) 
                : sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i)) . PHP_EOL; 
        $mysql_query("UPDATE `attend` SET `total_hrs` = $new WHERE `id` = $id");
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is $id being set?

Comment: You have a $ before your mysql_query.

Comment: @TeeDeJee 's comment should be the answer

Comment: I removed the $ before the MySQL_query but still no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for all the help guys, but I figured out that a simple query does the trick...

```
UPDATE `attend`
            SET `total_hrs` = if((`sub_hrs` - truncate(`sub_hrs`,0)) < 0.5, truncate(`sub_hrs`,0), ((truncate(`sub_hrs`,0)) + 0.5))
            WHERE `date` = '$date'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an array $new[] in below line.

```
  $new[] = (fmod($i, 1) > 0.5 
            ? sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i + 0.5) 
            : sprintf("%2.f", (float) (int) $i)) . PHP_EOL;
```

But in query you are passing only $new variable which will not work as you will not get any value in $new variable.

```
    $mysql_query("UPDATE `attend` SET `total_hrs` = $new WHERE `id` = $id");
```

Comment: I know my method is wrong, any suggestion on how to rather loop through the table data and update `total_hrs` field with the rounding criteria set in the $new array?

Comment: What are you getting in $new[] array for a particular $id? If you are getting more than 1 values then do you want to sum all those value and store in attend column in table for that $id?

Comment: $id is an auto increment integer, the $new[] array consists of all the total hours employees have worked for the day (which can be 6.9, 8.5, 8.6 etc), the loop script (in the $new array) rounds these hours worked to the bottom of a half an hour thus 6.9 becomes 6.5, 8.5 stays the same 8.5 and 8.6 becomes 8.5 etc. But I do not want to change the original hours in `sub_hrs`, thus I want to write the new rounded time to the `total_hrs` field...

Comment: are you storing comma seperated values in sub_hrs? Do you want to store the sum of all into attend column?